# python - nested dictionary as argument

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Having following example dictionary:

```
dict = {
    'key1': {
        'nested_key1': {
            'more_nested_key1': 'a_value'
        }
    },
    'key2': {
        'a_key': 'some_value'
    }
}
```

I need a function that takes the dict and any number of nested keys and performs an action on the value. For instance:

```
def replace(dict, '['key1']['nested_key1']['more_nested_key1']', 'new_value')
```

would replace 'a_value' with 'new_value'. I am new to python, any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Inside function you can do `dict['key1']['nested_key1']['more_nested_key1'] = 'new_value'`

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey I think they want to pass the keys as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a list of keys to the function, iterate through all but the last one of them until you get to the innermost dictionary, and then assign to the final key:

```
def replace(dict, keys, value):
    d = dict
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[key]
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the keys (except for the last), getting the next dict down each time. Then for the final key, set the item in the last dict to `value`

```
def replace(dct, *keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
       dct = dct[key]
    dct[keys[-1]] = value
```

Usage:

```
replace(dict, 'key1', 'nested_key1', 'more_nested_key1', value='new_value')
```